I'm getting a conan "FileNotFoundError"
I'm using conan 1.55.0 to package my project and upload it to the Artifactory.
I'm running this command:
'conan export-pkg -f <conan_file_path.py> <artifactory recipe>'

My conan.py package command is this:
self.copy('*', src=f'{path(os.getcwd()).parent.parent}', dst='CommonTracker', excludes='.gitkeep', ignore_case=True)

I'm getting a 'FileNotFoundError' which reference to the conan cache about missing html file, which exist in the project but not exist in the cache, why is the file not gets copied to the cache?
I used this code before and it always worked. the problem began a few days ago.
please help.
I tried to exclude the html file by adding *.html to the 'excludes' parameter but it didn't work.
I also tried to use a different machine and I got the same error, only this time it was about some cpp file and not html.

Conan 1.55 is 2 years old now, and also superseded by Conan 2, very recommended to update as soon as possible. Also, even in Conan 1, things like self.copy() were replaced by copy(self, ...), it would be recommended to use them instead. For the question, I think there is not enough information without having the full recipe and a full layout of the local files that are in the conanfile and parent folders, so maybe a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues would be better to formulate the question with full details.
